# jQuery - changing image source dynamically flashes original image first then changes it

Tags: jquery, image

EDIT: I am looking for an all jquery solution here, I can't edit the html/css to initially not show the image.

I've tried doing this a bunch of different ways, however it still flashes the original image before changing it over to the new source image.

I realize the simple answer is:

```
$('.logo').attr('src', newlogosrc);
```

However, I've also tried some stuff like:

```
$('.logo').hide();
$('.logo').attr('src', newlogosrc);
$(this).delay(500).show();
```

Which just delays the whole process (waits half a second, then flashes original image, then changes it to new image).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to prevent the initial display of the image:

1. Put an inline `style="display: none;"` on the image tag itself.
2. Add a CSS rule `.logo {display: none;}` that is active by default.

You could, of course, also hide a containing div instead of the image itself if that was more practical and you can use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` if you prefer.

Javascript runs AFTER the DOM loads so unless the image is hidden at the HTML level (before JS runs), it may show initially.

Once one of those two CSS rules is active by default, the image will not initially display and you can use javascript to set the `.src` attribute appropriately and then show the image using javascript.

Also, assuming the image is already hidden with one of the two options above, the proper JS to load a new image and then show it is this:

```
$('.logo').load(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).attr("src", newlogosrc);
```

This shows it when the new image has succesfully loaded.

Comment: I should have also noted, that I can't change the HTML/CSS - I was hoping for an all-jquery solution.

Comment: @Buchannon - You can't solve this only with JS.  The page loads before the JS can access the page.  So, it's a timing race.  Sometimes, if the image isn't in the browser cache and takes a little while to load, the JS might hide it before the image bits start showing, but other times (when it's in the browser cache or loads quickly), it will display before any JS runs.  The ONLY reliable way to do it is with an inline style or CSS rule that hides it immediately as the `<img>` tag is parsed.